# Need to run existing windows form application in dot net core with telerik controls

Tags: winforms, .net-core, telerik

We have existing windows base application which is build in old dot net framework. Our clients needs to run this application using dot net core (latest framework). But telerik control is mandatory for that.

Is anyone can help for this?
How can we start?
Is that possible to run old windows application in dot net core?

Comment: its unclear what you are asking, can you give us some more info. What dotnet framework is used now ? is telerik already used in the current application or is it needed in the new version ? Please provide us with as much details as possible, how else can we possible help you

Comment: winforms designer is not working if we are running telerik winforms project in visual studio 2019 preview with dotnet core 3.0 framework.I read some blogs for that we get some interesting things like dotnet core does not support winforms designer till now. I think microsoft is working for this. But our client needed this project in dotnet core 3.0 along with winforms not wpf. Also telerik control is not supported in dotnet core winforms. do you have any specific way to move in this direction?

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik controls are not mandatory. However, the process is still complex. Currently, the best approach is to have a standard project that shares the files with the .Net Core one. Or convert the project to .Net Core after it is ready.

The following blog post describes the process:  [How to Port Desktop Applications to .NET Core 3.0](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-port-desktop-applications-to-net-core-3-0)

I hope this helps.
Regards,